# AChartEngine - Line width of axes

Tags: android, width, line, axis, achartengine

Is there a possibility to set the **line width of the x-/y-axis** in `AChartEngine`?

By default, both axes have a line width of 1 pixel. I would like to set the width to 1 dp (or whatever), but I don't find a method for that in the [Javadoc](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/index.html). So, does anybody know if it's possible?

Comment: are you able to change that width using any method?

Comment: That's actually my question ;-) I don't know a method for doing that.

Comment: You can set the color, but not the width of the axis line.

Comment: Okay, I thought so :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by creating a custom chart and overrode `draw()`.

```
public class CustomChart extends CombinedXYChart {

public CustomChart(XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset, XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, String[] types) {
    super(dataset, renderer, types);
}

@Override
public void draw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas, int x, int y, int width, int height, android.graphics.Paint paint) {
    float strokeWidth = paint.getStrokeWidth();
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);  // set your axes line width
    super.draw(canvas, x, y, width, height, paint);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
}
}
```

Comment: @Namelos Can i use this function in Bar Chart?

Comment: @user406090 yes you can, the issue you can find with this code is that if you show the grid the lines will be the same width that the axis, and this could not be what you need. I have send a request (with the code included) to the project owner to add this functionality to the library [see issue here](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=392)

Comment: @namenlos how to use this class .. m unable to solve the issue